# Can we prove that in any ring $a+a=2a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Before I get to the question itself I want to clarify a few things:

Definition for a ring from my textbook (translated (not that well) to English and then shortened by yours truly,so please pardon any mistakes):

Set $R$ is called a ring if it has two operations defined on it, which we will note as $+$ and $\times$, if both have the commutative and associative properties and they are tied together with distributive properties.

1. $a+b=b+a$ and $ab=ba$
2. $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$ and $a(bc) = (ab)c$
3. $(a+b)c=ac+bc$

With that out of the way, I want to ask if it's possible to prove that in any ring $R$ for any $a$ from $R$, $a+a=2a$?

If it isn't, then can we prove that for any $+$ and $\times$ defined on the set of natural numbers for any natural number $n$, $n+n=2n$?

The reason I put my text book's definition of a ring is because I have looked through forums for similar questions already, but they define addition there after defining natural numbers with Peano axioms (things like $a+1=\mathrm{successor}(a)$ and similar things). I would like to know if there exists a proof where we don't define operator $+$ more than the definition above.

Comment: How do you define$2a$... apart from being $a+a$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: Well, one could define $2:=1+1$, but then $2a=a+a$ followos trivially from the distributive property. So either way, it's pretty close to being true by definition.

Comment: Yes because all rings are $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras.

Comment: Even ignoring the fact that it is a ring, as a *group* $G$ with group operation $\star$ you can have for $n\in \Bbb N$ and $a\in G$ the notation $na$ to be *defined* to mean $na := \underbrace{a\star a\star a\star \cdots \star a}_{n~\text{times}}$ or optionally $a^n := \underbrace{a\star a\star a\star \cdots \star a}_{n~\text{times}}$, whichever is more convenient.  See for example Dummit and Foote chapter 1 section 1.1.  In the case of a ring, the first is used for the "addition" while the second notation is used for the "multiplication."

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: 2*a as an element of R that is the result of multiplication between 2 and a. Multiplication is defined on R(R being obviously the arbitrary set we defined + and x on) just by following the rules above

Comment: It's a Russian textbook by Kurosch. I don't think it has a translation

Comment: Is the multiplicative unity - that is $1$ - part of your definition of a ring or not? We require $1$ to be able to define $2=1+1$. Different textbooks either include $1$ or not.

Comment: No it wasn't defined there

Comment: If $1$ is not defined, then $2$ is not defined either, and the relationship $a+a=2a$ cannot be proven.

Comment: However, $0$ is also missing in your definition, and all textbooks do agree that the additive unity $0$ _is_ part of a ring. And that each element $a$ has an additive inverse $-a$.

Comment: Those things are derived later from the definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally $1 + 1 = 2$; there are rings of characteristic $2$ (like mod $2$ arithmetic), where $1 + 1 = 0$, but in these rings $2 = 0$ so you still kind of have $1 + 1 = 2$ in a sense.

Anyway $2 a = (1 + 1) a = 1 a + 1 a = a + a$. And this always holds.

Comment: In the mod $2$ case we just have $2 = 0$ so no exception to the rule $1+1 = 2$ is required.

Comment: But can we say that 1a=a?  can we define a multiplicative identity in a ring and be certain that it's the only one such element?

Comment: If $1$ and $1'$ are two multiplicative identites, then $1\cdot1'=1$ since $1'$ is an identity but also $1\cdot 1'=1'$ since $1$ is an identity. So all together $1=1\cdot 1'=1'$ and both identites are actually the same.

Comment: @Iamtrash As C. Brendel says, if a multiplicative identity exists, it is unique. However, there are a few things to note. First, not all authors require rings to have multiplicative identities, and second, we might have $ab = a$ for certain elements $a,b$ with $b\neq 1.$ For example, I have a ring $R$ in my pocket with distinct elements $0, 1, x,$ and $1 + x.$ In this ring, $a + a = 0$ for any $a,$ and multiplication is commutative and satisfies the rule that $x^2 = x.$ However, although $x\cdot x = x,$ $x\neq 1$! This ring is more commonly known as $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2 - x).$